# Crashing as a result of turning off the wireless lan interface on a Dell E6410?

Tags: wireless, kernel

Lately (this past few days after an update) my laptop started acting strange.

The meaning by acting strange is that:

1. Ubuntu just crashes whenever I fiddle with the wlan.
2. The internet has become ridiculously slow.

Using speedtest.net points out that when I'm using Ubuntu the download speed graph is very "edgy", the upload seems to be fine.
On Windows though the download speed is just fine (around 50mbps, the Ubuntu test didn't get past the 1mbps).

I think it started after the latest kernel update (to `2.3.68.11` if I remember correctly).
Tried to update it again but it went even worse than it was before.

**Edit:**

I've done a speedtest on a live cd with ubuntu 11.04(same as I have installed)
And it works great, the installed version is corrupted I guess. how can I fix it?

My system is as follows:

```
Dual boot: Windows 7 64bit, Ubuntu 11.04 32bit
Laptop: Dell E6410, i7 4 GB Ram
Wireless network card: DW1520 Wireless-N Half-Mini Card
```

Comment: Have you tried to boot into an older live-CD to compare if there's any difference with speedtest? You could e.g. boot into a 10.10 live-CD and try it.

Comment: @N.N. I'll have to download and try. I've never experienced this before, computer has been running smoothly with 11.04 so far.

Comment: @N.N. I've done the test, seems fine.

Comment: Do you get bad speeds on a 11.04 live-CD too?

Comment: No. Actually it's great, 15mbps. How can I reinstall the network drivers?

Comment: Can you recall what you did so that the network started to behave badly? If you can undo that you might get the same performance as the 11.04 live-CD. Also you could just try to make a new wlan profile in the network settings and try the default settings or mess around with them til it works.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)